# Resources are missing from JAR file after repackage with spring boot maven plugin

Tags: maven, docker, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin, docker-maven-plugin

My application uses some additional files which I have inside the resource folder. When I do the regular build with Maven and package my app into JAR, I can see all my resources in case I unzip this archive.

But when I create a docker image I use spring-boot-maven-plugin to make my JAR archive executable. For some reason **my resources aren't being added to the new repacked JAR**. Moreover I **can not even unzip it** because it is corrupted.

Here is the way I set the repackage goal in my pom.xml:

```
<id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>ApplicationName</mainClass>
                        <executable>true</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>--spring.profiles.active=prod</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <!--<addResources>true</addResources>-->
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!--<includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>-->
                                <!--<layout>JAR</layout>-->
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

I want to add that when I run my image in docker it works fine **but all the needed resources are missing**.

Has anyone run into the same problem? Or maybe you can suggest how to fix it.

Comment: I think corrupted JAR is a clue. Create simple project and apply spring-boot-maven-plugin. If target JAR is corrupted, something is wrong with your environment. If target JAR is valid, add piece by piece your application until get corrupted JAR.

Comment: @michaldo as I already mentioned the target JAR is okay, but when I repack it ti make it executable it gets corrupted. So I guess the problem is in repackage part...

Comment: @michaldo The repackaged jar is actually working, spring is booting with the integrated tomcat server and working properly. The only issue is that the resources are not accessible anymore.